# Simple REST WCF Service Example Code - Endpoint not found

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, self-hosting

I was trying an example partially from Chapter 5 - *RESTful .Net*, but couldn't make it work for some reason (receiving 404-Not found).

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

[ServiceContract]
public class RestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Hosting")]
    public void Hosting()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RestService::Hosting()");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(RestService));
        var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(RestService), new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8080/Hosting");
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

        host.Open();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It works (returns status-code OK) if I use WebServiceHost as follows

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(RestService), new Uri("http://localhost:8080"));
        host.Open();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

So the question is how to make it work with ServiceHost (without any configuration file etc. if possible) ?

Comment: can you ping the url you are trying to access?

Comment: @Zach Not sure that I understand why ping is relevant... I'm testing it with a simple tool http://cmdhttprequest.codeplex.com/ and it works if I switch to WebServiceHost.

Comment: After I changed the endpoint address from "http://localhost:8080/Hosting" to "http://localhost:8080" it worked. I was always providing full address for this parameter for other type of service endpoints, but that is not the case for this time (it somehow combines UriTemplate with endpoint address I suppose).

Answer (score 1):

**WebServiceHost** creates an EndPoint for you, nothing wrong if you continue using it. Refer this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/justinjsmith/archive/2007/07/02/webservicehost-vs-servicehost.aspx) for more details...

But you can also add below configuration to your service configuration to use **ServiceHost**, I have given an example, you can change it to reflect your service classes.

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="YourService.DateTimeService" behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior">
                <endpoint address="Basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DifferentBindings.IDateTime">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>             
                <endpoint address="Web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DifferentBindings.IDateTime" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />                
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/DifferentBindings/DateTimeService/" />                      
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
                </behavior>             
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I was actually trying to find a way to add simple REST functionality to existing ServiceHost (without changing any code or creating a new host). I read the link that you post before asking this question, there are some comments which complains about the same issue that I am asking for (endpoint not found). Thanks for example configuration.

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue after adding the configuration I have given in the example ?

Answer (score 0):

So I was curious how complex this will be with WCF. Tried it out. It's streight forward.

I used [this tutorial](http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2013/09/simple-steps-for-restful-service.html) to create a simple service that has a doWork method that expects a string and returns a greeting.

Greeting:

```
[DataContract]
public class Greeting
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Str { get; set; }
}
```

Svc Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "sayHello/{name}/")]
Greeting DoWork(string name);
```

Svc Impl:

```
public class GreetingService : IGreetingService
{
    public Greeting DoWork(string name)
    {
        return new Greeting {Str = string.Format("Hello {0}", name)};
    }
}
```

Then you can first test it by:

- Right click on the svc file in visual studio > view in browser
- add 'sayHello/test' to the url
- see the greeting in the browser

A consumer for this can be implemented in AngularJS using either the $http oder the $resource service

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="restTest">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        // set up the app
        var app = angular.module('restTest', ['ngResource']);

        // create a controller
        app.controller('RestTestCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $resource) {
            // initial greeting
            $scope.greeting = "Not greeted yet";

            // say hello, consuming the svc using $http
            $scope.sayHelloHttp = function () {
                var url = "http://localhost:7507/GreetingService.svc/sayHello/" + $scope.inName + "/";
                $http.get(url).
                    success(function(data) {
                        $scope.greeting = data.Str;
                    });
            }

            // say hello, consuming the svc using $resource
            $scope.sayHelloRest = function () {
                var GreetingSvc = $resource("http://localhost:7507/GreetingService.svc/sayHello/:name");
                GreetingSvc.get({ name: $scope.inName }, function(data) {
                    $scope.greeting = data.Str;
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body ng-controller="RestTestCtrl">
        <!-- bind the value of this input to the scope -->
        <input type="text" ng-model="inName"/>
        <button ng-click="sayHelloHttp()">$http</button>
        <button ng-click="sayHelloRest()">$resource</button>
        <!-- bind the greeting property -->
        <div>{{greeting}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I guess everything above can be expressed more advance but it should give you a basic and working example to get started.